# Error in code blocks and shows segmentation fault in online compilation?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, codeblocks

The following code causes code blocks to stop. It is displayed as some problem caused the program to close. when i tried online compilation it showes as segmentation fault(core dumped). I couldn't find out what it is!

```
//Hash table

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int option,i,key;
    char value[10], hashtab[10][10];

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        strcpy(hashtab[i],'\0');
    }

    printf("\nEnter 1-Insert ANY-Exit");
    scanf("%d",&option);
    while(option==1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the Value: ");
        scanf("%s",value);
        key=keygen(value);
        strcpy(hashtab[key],value);
     }

    for(i=0;option==2&&i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s",hashtab[i]);
    }
}

int keygen(char *value)
{
    int i,key=0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(value);i++)
    {
        key=key+value[i];
    }
    return key;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` used in the `for` loop should be arguments as below,

```
  char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

Ideally the second argument passed should be the string pointed to by `src`.

Making it to, `strcpy(hashtab[i], "\0");` should work.

Comment: True, and `hashtab[i] = 0;` would probably be preferred in this case, or better still `char hashtub[10][10] = {};` if the compiler isn't from the stone-age, though the former would likely perform better.

Comment: Yes. Simple assignment can be used.